# How to remove a special character in a string in a file using linux commands

Tags: linux

I need to remove the character `:` from a file. Ex: I have numbers in the following format:

```
b3:07:4d
```

I want them to be like:

```
b3074d
```

I am using the following command:

```
grep ':' source.txt | sed -e 's/://' > des.txt
```

I am new to Linux. The file is quite big & I want to make sure I'm using the write command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do without the grep:

```
sed -e 's/://g'  source.txt > des.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-i` option edits the file in place.

```
sed -i 's/://' source.txt
```

Comment: If you want a backup, provide a suffix to -i: `-ibak`

Answer (score 1):

the first part isn't right as it'll completely omit lines which don't contain :

below is untested but should be right.   The g at end of the regex is for global, means it should get them all.

```
sed -e 's/://g' source.txt > out.txt
```

updated to better syntax from Jon Lin's answer but you still want the /g I would think